# RegEx pattern to validate String

Tags: regex

Let me make my question Simple what I want is I am using white list Regex pattern to avoid xss and sql injection so as my allowed character in string is [A-Za-z0-9,()[]{}\"\:./_\s] and I want to restrict occurrence of -- in any coming request from client but it should allow - or jjdfasd-dsfads-12321 string

In short it below test cases should run successfully

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegExTest {

private static Pattern xssAttackPattern;

private static final String XSS_ATTACK_REGULAR_EXPRESSION1 = "-?[A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\"\\:./_\\s]*";


public static Pattern getXSSAttackPattern1() {
    xssAttackPattern = Pattern.compile(XSS_ATTACK_REGULAR_EXPRESSION1);
    return xssAttackPattern;
}

public static boolean hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(String value) {

    if (getXSSAttackPattern1().matcher(value).matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



public static void main(String arg[]) {

    System.out.println(" :::::: Regular Expression ::::::");
    regexTest();

}

private static void regexTest() {

    String str1 = "-dsfdsfddsfd2112212s";
    String str2 = "--dsfdsfddsfd2112212s";
    String str3 = "-dsfdsfdd-sfd2112212s";
    String str4="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_business.rss?id=121132511$@#$@$@#%242444+gfghgfhg";
    String str5="(.:[]{}";
    String str6="--";
    String str7="-";

    System.out.println("String::" + str1 + "::Result::"
            + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(str1));
    System.out.println("String::" + str2 + "::Result::"
            + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(str2));
    System.out.println("String::" + str3 + "::Result::"
            + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(str3));
    System.out.println("String::" + str4 + "::Result::"
            + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(str4));
    System.out.println("String::" + str5 + "::Result::"
            + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(str5));
    System.out.println("String::" + str6 + "::Result::"
            + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(str6));
    System.out.println("String::" + str7 + "::Result::"
            + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(str7));
}
```

}

Comment: "allow multiple occurrence of A-Z 0-9 and a-z but (-) occurrence only zero or one in string."  I can't understand this, the sentence contradicts itself.

Comment: What with the backslash orgy in your proposed regexp???

Comment: @Harshil - so do you want your regex to match the above strings or to discard them ? They are far from A-Za-z0-9 and a dash only... And please explain the slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current regex matches

- a string consisting of a single `-` character, or
- a string consisting of a sequence of letters, digits, and some special characters, or
- an empty string

If you would like to change it to allow zero or one dash `-` only at the beginning of the string, remove the *OR* character `|` from your expression; if you would like to match at most one dash anywhere in the string, change expression to

```
[A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\"\\:./_\\s]*-?[A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\"\\:./_\\s]*
```

**EDIT 1:** If you need to avoid two *consecutive* dashes, you can use this expression with [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
([A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\"\\:./_\\s]|(?<!-)-)*
```

The `(?<!-)-` part of the expression above matches a dash unless it is preceded by another dash.

**EDIT 2:** If you have strings of 10000+ length, a positive regex solution is not as good as a negative one. Instead of looking for `myString.matches(positiveExpr)`, it is much more efficient to look for `!myString.matches(negativeExpr)`, and use this expression for your negative match. In other words, instead of specifying an expression defining the string that you want, you could define a much simpler expression for the string that you do not want:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\"\\:./_\\s]|--
```

NOTE: Sanitizing your strings is not the best way to avoid SQL injection attacks; using parameterized statements is.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but still it is not satisfying my above test case class

Comment: I just [ran your code at ideone](http://ideone.com/7pNL2), and it produces a good sequence of answers: first is a match, second and third are not, because both have two dashes. Fourth has invalid characters (@, #, $, %), fifth does not have illegal characters or dashes, so it matches; sixth is a double dash, and seventh matches fine.

Comment: what I want is my third string should match as there is no two consecutive --

Comment: @Harshil I did not realize that you were looking for *consecutive* dashes. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Hi as I am getting issue with you given Regex pattern for very large string approx (14965 characters)which is read from some file I have have same failure trace as in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681928/my-regex-is-causing-a-stack-overflow-in-java-what-am-i-missing